# If $\hat{f}$ is a real function, then $f$ is even.

Tags: fourier-transform

I have the following exercise:

Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R})\cap \cal{L}^1$. 
Show that:

$$\hat{f}(\xi) \in \mathbb{R} \;\;\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R} \iff f \text{ is even.} $$

I did the ($\Leftarrow$) part just using basic properties of Fourier and change of variable. But my problem is at the ($\Rightarrow$) part.

My attempt:

$$\overline{\hat{f}(\xi)}=\hat{f}(\xi)$$

$$\overline{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-ix\xi} \, dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-ix\xi} \, dx$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ix\xi} \, dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-ix\xi} \, dx$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ix\xi}\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-ix\xi}\,dx$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ix\xi}\,dx=-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(-y)e^{iy\xi}\,dy$$

And I'm failing to conclude $f(x)=f(-x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ from this...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You made a mistake. The last identity should be From
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ix\xi}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(-y)e^{iy\xi}dy.$$

Comment: @xpaul, I don't see this. I did $y=-x$, then $dy/dx = -1$, then $dy=-dx$...

Comment: But integration limits changes from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to  $(+\infty,-\infty)$. Requires  a minus to reverse them back.

Comment: Yes. More precisely, the calculation made in your last passage is wrong: Taking $y = -x$ we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx  =- \int_\infty^{-\infty} f(-y)e^{iy\xi}dy =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-y)e^{iy\xi}dy.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have $f$ and $g$, where $g(x)=f(-x)$, and $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ix\xi}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)e^{ix\xi}dx.$$

By the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ix\xi}dx\right)e^{-i\xi y}dy=\sqrt{2\pi} f(y)$$
and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)e^{ix\xi}dx\right)e^{-i\xi y}dy=\sqrt{2\pi} g(y).$$

Therefore, $f=g$.

Comment: Observation: I'm not being very rigorous here. I'm using those integrals are well defined, which may not be the case. But, the Fourier inverse is always defined for tempered distributions and using that I can formalize my calculation.

Comment: I follow what you've done, but why do I have the first equation?